# ssl installed but not secure

Tags: apache, ssl, centos, vps

I installed the ssl, but browsers are showing it's not secure.

I bought my ssl from ssls.com

this is my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot /root/public_html
ServerName www.example.com
ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example_com.privatekey
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/example_com.ca-bundle
```

It's showing my ssl is self-signed, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Post your entire `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Actually I fixed the issue. Listen was set to "listen 80" and I changed it to "listen 443"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I fixed the issue. Listen was set to

```
listen 80
```

and I changed it to

```
listen 443
```